# implement webassembly angular 12 error load .wasm

Tags: javascript, angular, webassembly

I try to load .wasm into my project like that, it's work for angular 5 but get error when in angular 12

> Blockquote ./node_modules/file-loader/dist/cjs.js?name=wasm/fibonacci.wasm!./wasm/fibonacci.wasm - Error: Module parse failed: magic header not detected

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs'
import { filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators'

import * as Module from './../../wasm/fibonacci.js'
import '!!file-loader?name=wasm/fibonacci.wasm!../../wasm/fibonacci.wasm'

@Injectable()
class WasmService {
  module: any

  wasmReady = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false)

  constructor() {
    this.instantiateWasm('wasm/fibonacci.wasm')
  }

  private async instantiateWasm(url: string) {
    // fetch the wasm file
    const wasmFile = await fetch(url)

    // convert it into a binary array
    const buffer = await wasmFile.arrayBuffer()
    const binary = new Uint8Array(buffer)

    // create module arguments
    // including the wasm-file
    const moduleArgs = {
      wasmBinary: binary,
      onRuntimeInitialized: () => {
        this.wasmReady.next(true)
      },
    }

    // instantiate the module
    this.module = Module(moduleArgs)
  }

  public fibonacci(input: number): Observable<number> {
    return this.wasmReady.pipe(filter(value => value === true)).pipe(
      map(() => {
        return this.module._fibonacci(input)
      })
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: would you mind creating a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular-ivy) with a minimum reproducible version of the issue you are facing?

Comment: I don’t understand why you’re trying to use a file loader for your wasm if you’re fetching it anyway? Just include it as an asset

Answer (score 0):

To be able to load a wasm file, there are some requirements,

At first, you have to be sure your web server reports wasm files mime type as 'application/wasm'.

Next, you will need being able to load .wasm file in  your angular application.

if you use webpack < 4 , you may use https://www.npmjs.com/package/wasm-loader and not file-loader.
in webpack5 , that 's battery included.

Comment: can you clarify your last statement "in webpack5 , that 's battery included"? What is included in WebPack 5? Do you have a code example?

Comment: @Dude0001 https://webpack.js.org/configuration/experiments/  

https://github.com/ballercat/minimal-webpack5-wasm-demo